# How reliable are the Package Usage metrics?

Tags: trigger, managed-package, isv

Our managed package is installed in many orgs and we're trying to determine what features are being used.

I've downloaded the [Package Usage](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.distribution_package_usage.htm&type=5) details from one particular org, and there are definitely things missing from it.

#### Example 1

A trigger on one our of objects isn't being reported in the Package Usage, but I've 100% confirmed records are being created/edited/deleted from that object.  The trigger is definitely kicking in, because it is updating other data.

#### Example 2

In another org, the object in question isn't being used at all, but the `num_events` column has values, but not the `num_creates`/`num_reads`/`num_updates`/`num_deletes`.

#### Example 3

The triggers on some of our objects are broken up into a before and after trigger.  For one of our customers, the Package Usage is showing ~10k for the before trigger, but only ~10 for the after trigger.  Shouldn't these numbers be similar?

Is the Package Usage feature actually reliable?

Are there nuances to it that we need to be aware of?